# How to clone a existing Laravel website on Plesk?

Tags: php, laravel, clone, plesk

I am new to Laravel and trying to clone an existing website to place it on dev.domain.com so I can work on it. But its not working.

1- I copied all the files and database and set new db/user in .env file.

2- When I run "Composer Install" it failed at "php artisan optimize" and says "ErrorException]Undefined index: HTTP_HOST"

3- When I run "php artisan key:generate" it failed and error stays the same i.e
  [ErrorException]
  Undefined index: HTTP_HOST

Please guide

Comment: Sounds like you have some custom code that is using HTTP_HOST.  However, `artisan optimize` is a post task and an error there shouldn't have affected the composer install (see composer.json)

Comment: how to find what code is causing that bug?

Comment: Grep or search the code base for HTTP_HOST?  Using very verbose (`-vvv`) with artisan may give you some insight.

Comment: OK, I found it its in service providers.

Comment: now when I navigate only one problem its taking me to old URL from where I took clone.